# Using member-function-pointer with parameter-pack

Tags: c++, function-pointers

```
template<typename Callback, typename Callee, typename... Args>
std::function<void(Args...)> safe_bind(Callback callback, std::shared_ptr<Callee> shared) {
    std::weak_ptr<Callee> weak = shared;
    return std::function<void(Args...)>([callback, weak](Args... args){
        if(auto shared_ptr = weak.lock()) {
            // std::bind(callback, ptr)(args...);
            // callback(ptr, args...);
            (shared_ptr.get()->*callback)(args...);
        }
    });
}
```

This function is like `std::bind` but the returned function is safe to call when the bound object is destroyed.
It fails to compile because `Args` couldn't be deduced. I want to associate `Callback = void(Args...)`. However I cannot find a way to replace `Callback` with a std::function or function pointer type with a parameter pack.

```
safe_bind(Callback callback, std::shared_ptr<Callee> shared) {          // does not compile
safe_bind(void(*)(Callee*, Args...) callback, std::shared_ptr<Callee> shared) {  // does not compile
safe_bind((void(*)(Callee*, Args...)) callback, std::shared_ptr<Callee> shared) {// does not compile
...
```

How to achieve this?
`callback` will be mostly `&Class::method`, so a solution without `std::function` is preferable (if possible) to avoid allocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't wrap the lambda in a `std::function` and use perfect forwarding of any argument types. You can also deal with other callables by using [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which automatically deals with pointer-to-member(-functions), functions, and objects with an `operator()`:

```cpp
template<typename Callback, typename Callee>
auto safe_bind(Callback&& callback, std::shared_ptr<Callee> shared) {
    return [weak = std::weak_ptr{shared}, callback = std::forward<Callback>(callback)](auto&&... args) {
        if (auto shared_ptr = weak.lock()) {
            std::invoke(callback, *shared_ptr, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        }
    };
}
```

If the function is always a pointer-to-member-function, you can deduce the type of the arguments from the pointer:

```cpp
template<typename Callee, typename Res, typename... Args>
auto safe_bind(Res (Callee::* callback)(Args...), std::shared_ptr<Callee> shared) {
    return [weak = std::weak_ptr<Callee>{shared}, callback](Args... args) {
        if (auto shared_ptr = weak.lock()) {
            // The std::forward here moves arguments that are passed by value
            ((*shared_ptr).*callback)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
}
```